# Combinatorial Formula for Given Number of Items

Tags: combinatorics

Problem:
How many ways can you arrange 4 squares and 5 triangles

This is different from $n$ choose $k$ because I there is a specific quantity for each item in the list. Nor can I use the permutation formula as the items have quantities greater than 1.

So how do I solve this? Is there sort of formula that generalize how to solve the number of Permutation if the list's items have quantities?

Comment: You have $9$ slots and, say, you start by placing the squares (once the squares are placed, you are done).  Therefore...

Comment: What do you mean by "arrange", Yashvasin? There are infinitely many different places in the plane where you can put the first square, and infinitely many orientations for it once you've decided where to put it. Similarly for those other eight polygons. Do all the squares look different, or are they all indistinguishable? Lots of extra information needed, to make this a reasonable question.